# What is a pythonic way to print a string multiple times on one line, separated by spaces?

Tags: python

I want to print a string multiple times on a line separated by spaces.

I've tried a few versions of string multiplication, like `string * 3`.
I've also tried `" ".join()` but I get spaces between every character instead of each string. I think join needs a list not a string.

Here is the verbose version of my code that works:
`fout.write(info[2]+" "+info[2]+" "+info[2]+'\n')`

And another version where I insert the letter x before each string:
`fout.write("x"+info[2]+" x"+info[2]+" x"+info[2]+'\n')`

My code works but it seems like there is a more pythonic way, like the version where I'm printing the whole list called info instead of just info[2] repeated:
`fout.write(" ".join(x)+'\n')` where x is the list.

Comment: `" ".join(string for _ in range(3))` or `" ".join([string]*3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the string in a list

```
print(' '.join(['hello']*3))

'hello hello hello'
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to vote, so I'll just say here that I like this one the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

String multiplication is the right idea.

```py
print(((string+' ') * 3).rstrip())
```

`rstrip()` removes the trailing space only

If your string contains a trailing space, then `rstrip()` will incorrectly remove it. In that case, use slicing instead:

```py
print(((string+' ') * 3)[:-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would do this:

```
' '.join([string for _ in range(3)])
```

Using a list with `str.join` is faster as Python would have  exhausted the generator expression inside into a list anyway.